# save image after destroy() in Cropper.js

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

I'm using cropper.js and dont know how to save image after destroy(). I need destroy() to keep only cropped image, and delete leftovers. On save button I am getting error something like "Cannot create blob from null"
Any ideas?

```js
$(".dz-crop").on('click', function() {
                
                    image.src = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                        maxHeight: 2000,
                        maxWidth: 2000,
                        imageSmoothingEnabled: false,
                        imageSmoothingQuality: 'high',
                    }).toDataURL('image/jpeg');
                    cropper.destroy();
                    return false;
                });
                $('#save').off('click.cropImg').on('click.cropImg', function() {

                    cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                        maxHeight: 2000,
                        maxWidth: 2000,
                        imageSmoothingEnabled: false,
                        imageSmoothingQuality: 'high',
                    }).toBlob(function(blob) {
                        var file = new FormData();
                        file.append('file', blob);
                        file.append('id', $this.attr('rel'));
                        file.append('source', $this.data('source'));
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'URL',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: file,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function(data)
                            {
                                console.log("success)
                            },
                            error: ajaxFailed
                        });
                    }, 'image/jpeg')
                    return false;
                });
```